# Is there a way to obtain a nested array of objects according to their location Amazon S3, PHP SDK?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have the following:

```
$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    "Bucket" => $bucket,
    "Prefix" => ""
));


foreach ($objects as $key => $object) {
    var_dump($object);
}
```

This gives me an array of all the objects in the root directory of my bucket, however I want to know if there is any way to get a more organized response in which the array is nested according to each folder.

Comment: is your question how to get a tree view of everything that is in the bucket? like some recursive ls ?

Comment: exactly! that's what I am looking for :)

Comment: i am very curious what your `s3->getIterator` returns can you post a var_dump of `$objects` ... please add it to your question :) i don't know the whole SDK but my first thought is to make some recursive function

Comment: It will dump all the objects with their key no matter if they are folders or files all flat all files

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for not reading through all of it, but this page could hold the solution to your problem https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/function-Aws.recursive_dir_iterator.html

```
$objects = $s3->recursive_dir_iterator('s3://yourbucket/');
var_dump($objects);
```

Comment: My s3 instance comes from S3Client class, I think this is another class I should be using?